# Re-arranging flex items without absolute position

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I wonder if there is any way to achieve this kind of composition using flex box keeping the same structure (that order: box1, box2, box3 and box4).

I got this, but the `box4` is pushed down below the other boxes: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xRVEwW

```css
.container{
  width:600px;
  position:relative;
}
.box1, .box2, .box3, .box4{
  width: 200px;
}
.box2, .box4{
  margin:0 auto;
}
.box1{
  background:pink;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;  top:0;
}
.box2{
  background:lightgreen;
}
.box3{
  background:lightgrey;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;  top:0;
}
.box4{
  background:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="box1">Box 1.<br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </div>
  <div class="box2">Box 2.<br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam et fermentum odio, eget mattis quam. Curabitur rutrum lorem a augue egestas, ut rhoncus mi viverra.  Vivamus vehicula leo mauris.</div>
  <div class="box3">Box 3.<br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam et fermentum odio, eget mattis quam. Curabitur rutrum lorem a augue egestas, ut rhoncus mi viverra. Vivamus vehicula leo mauris, eu facilisis ex placerat id. Sed at ornare augue, id hendrerit nibh. Suspendisse sit amet velit sapien. Nulla sit amet ligula ac leo ultrices egestas et eget augue. Integer non metus tellus. Nam sed lorem et magna gravida laoreet. Vivamus et varius ipsum, ac mattis mi.</div>
  <div class="box4">Box 4.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if there is any way to achieve this kind of composition using flex box keeping the same structure.

Yes, there is a way to achieve he layout without any changes to the HTML. Here you go:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
}

.box1 { flex: 100%; order: 0; }
.box2 { flex: 80%;  order: 1; }
.box3 { flex: 100%; order: 3; }
.box4 { flex: 20%;  order: 2; }

.box1 { background: pink;      width: 200px; }
.box2 { background:lightgreen; width: 200px; }
.box3 { background:lightgrey;  width: 200px; }
.box4 { background:lightblue;  width: 200px; }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="box1">Box 1.<br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </div>
  <div class="box2">Box 2.<br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam et fermentum odio, eget mattis quam. Curabitur rutrum lorem a augue egestas, ut rhoncus mi viverra.  Vivamus vehicula leo mauris.</div>
  <div class="box3">Box 3.<br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam et fermentum odio, eget mattis quam. Curabitur rutrum lorem a augue egestas, ut rhoncus mi viverra. Vivamus vehicula leo mauris, eu facilisis ex placerat id. Sed at ornare augue, id hendrerit nibh. Suspendisse sit amet velit sapien. Nulla sit amet ligula ac leo ultrices egestas et eget augue. Integer non metus tellus. Nam sed lorem et magna gravida laoreet. Vivamus et varius ipsum, ac mattis mi.</div>
  <div class="box4">Box 4.</div>
</div>
```

[**revised codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NbNdwV?editors=1100)

Key points:

- Use a column direction, wrap-enabled flex container.
- Define a height for the container (so flex items know where to wrap).
- The first and third columns get full height (`flex-basis: 100%`, or shorthand `flex: 100%`).
- Second and fourth columns combine, so adjust their heights as necessary and use `order` property to move column 4 before column 3.

Comment: Great approach! Do you think is there any way to do it without specifying  the height value of the container?

Comment: That's a common request. Without the height on the container, there's nothing to force the flex items to wrap.

Answer (score 1):

Erase the flex properties and use float:

`float:left` on boxes 1 and 2, `float:right` on boxes 3 and 4. No HTML change necessary:

```css
.container{
  width:600px;
}
.box1, .box2, .box3, .box4{
  width: 200px;
}
.box1{
  background:pink;
  float: left;
}
.box2{
  background:lightgreen;
  float: left;
}
.box3{
  background:lightgrey;
  float: right;
}
.box4{
  background:lightblue;
  margin:0 auto;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="box1">Box 1.<br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </div>
  <div class="box2">Box 2.<br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam et fermentum odio, eget mattis quam. Curabitur rutrum lorem a augue egestas, ut rhoncus mi viverra.  Vivamus vehicula leo mauris.</div>
  <div class="box3">Box 3.<br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam et fermentum odio, eget mattis quam. Curabitur rutrum lorem a augue egestas, ut rhoncus mi viverra. Vivamus vehicula leo mauris, eu facilisis ex placerat id. Sed at ornare augue, id hendrerit nibh. Suspendisse sit amet velit sapien. Nulla sit amet ligula ac leo ultrices egestas et eget augue. Integer non metus tellus. Nam sed lorem et magna gravida laoreet. Vivamus et varius ipsum, ac mattis mi.</div>
  <div class="box4">Box 4.</div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eBZBYL

Comment: If you change the content of the boxes, it does not work. :-( http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yVOgjY

Comment: Yes, but I refered to your example. If box3  is shorter than box2, would you really  still want box4 to be underneath box2?

Answer (score 0):

- Wrap `box2` and `box4` in a common div
- Add `align-items: flex-start;` (or `baseline`) to `.container`

```css
.container{
  width:600px;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.box1, .box2, .box3, .box4{
  width: 200px;
}
.box1{
  background:pink;
}
.box2{
  background:lightgreen;
}
.box3{
  background:lightgrey;
}
.box4{
  background:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="box1">Box 1.<br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </div>
  <div>
    <div class="box2">Box 2.<br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam et fermentum odio, eget mattis quam. Curabitur rutrum lorem a augue egestas, ut rhoncus mi viverra. Vivamus vehicula leo mauris.</div>
    <div class="box4">Box 4.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box3">Box 3.<br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam et fermentum odio, eget mattis quam. Curabitur rutrum lorem a augue egestas, ut rhoncus mi viverra. Vivamus vehicula leo mauris, eu facilisis ex placerat id. Sed at ornare augue,
    id hendrerit nibh. Suspendisse sit amet velit sapien. Nulla sit amet ligula ac leo ultrices egestas et eget augue. Integer non metus tellus. Nam sed lorem et magna gravida laoreet. Vivamus et varius ipsum, ac mattis mi.</div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/borkdude/pen/VmaKRZ

Comment: That is the easy way :-) But... can I achieve the same without changing the structure?